# LibreOffice Draw multiple jpg to pdf

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, image-processing

How can I use LibreOffice Draw to convert multiple jpg files which were scanned, to a pdf file in a short way. Last time I had to create "New page" then "Insert -> Image" which was a *** for about 50 pages.

Comment: So you are thinking about Imagemagick and the `convert` command.

Comment: Does this workflow **need** to involve LibreOffice? I suppose there are other (command-line) tools to convert jpgs to pdf and then to merge the resulting pdfs into a single big pdf file. - EDIT: oops - @AndreaLazzarotto - one minute faster...

Comment: @tohuwawohu  because of checking files and sorting them command-line tools are not very handling for me.

Comment: Well, it is your duty to sort the pages beforehand anyway, regardless of the tool you will use to merge.

Comment: sometimes we had made pdfs and we need to insert one missed page or delete other page. regularly files  are not sortable by name. this time I really prefer a  tool with GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO this isn't a LO problem, but a workflow issue. The best solution depends on the specific requirements. If the requirements do vary, i would recommend trying to "modularize" the process, so variations will only affect one workflow module.

If you aren't sure which jpgs to convert (and if disk space isn't an issue), you should simply convert all of them (command line tool, e.g. imagemagick/convert).

To select the pdfs for merging, you could use a GUI tool like [PDFShuffler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pdfshuffler/). Just add all pdfs created in step one, and remove the ones that shouldn't be merged.

To edit the resulting single big PDF afterwards, use a tool like [PDFSam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfsam/) that lets you insert a single PDF in the middle of another PDF file.

### EDIT:

Use LO Impress' Photo Album feature: New Presentation -> Insert -> Media -> Photo Album. There, you can select multiple images to insert. If you're done, just export as PDF.

Comment: I wished some developer had put them all together in one app

Comment: @Mirza: Answer updated...

Comment: while it is a photo album, does it support any formats other than images like pdf ? even if not it will help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, i' not sure if i understand correctly. PDf isn't an image format, but images may be "embedded" in PDf files. Impress won't edit the PDF files, but you can save the impress file after creating the PDF, so you can modify the file with impress and re-create the PDf if required. It would be helpful if you describe your use case more exactly.

Comment: Tnx, that was useful enough and I got what I needed.

Comment: The LO Impress feature was very useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use ImageMagick (package name: `imagemagick`) for that job:

```
convert <SOURCE...> <TARGET>
```

Example:

```
convert *.jpg my-collection.pdf
```

Comment: shouldn't I wait a bit if there would be any more complete answer?

Comment: @Mirza: Sure, I just wanted to remind you of it in general.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at online tools for this, like https://smallpdf.com/jpg-to-pdf it's sometime easier than try to find a way using a specific software

Comment: I tested the site you mentioned. It's useful for small converts because there is a limit for pdf file for free users. editing pdf and merging them needs the pro version and most of all for me, uploading here is not free of charge and cost me additional cost